# Ruby on Rails - Optional user message when they submit their vote to database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app allows users to see a list of questions and allows them to vote for an option (uniquely). I have a `users` table, a `questions` table, an `options` table and an `answers` table.

I've created the migration to add the column `message` to the `answers` table and I can show the messages on the page, just need to actually send the message to the DB table - this is the button to allow the user to vote:

```
<%= link_to 'Vote', question_option_upvote_path(@question, option), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to vote for this option?' }, :class => 'voteNow', method: :post %>
```

I'm struggling to hook up the textarea to be sent when the user clicks to vote, I'm using simply `<%= text_area :message, autofocus: true %>` to create my textarea on it's own. Do I need to setup a whole form for this or is there a simple way to pull the contents when the user votes? My options controller is:

```
class OptionsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
        @option = @question.options.create(option_param)
        redirect_to question_path(@question)
    end

    def upvote
        @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
        @option = Option.find(params[:option_id])
        Answer.create(user_id: current_user.id, question_id: @question.id, option_id: @option.id)
        redirect_to question_path(@question)
    end

    private

    def option_param
        params.require(:option).permit(:option_text)
    end
end
```

Let me know if I need to include anything else in this message!

Comment: If your textarea isn't within a form, it wont be submitted anywhere when you click another link on the page. The two things are completely separate from one another. You should use a form for voting, and allow them to optionally include a message when you submit the form to vote.

Comment: So does that mean I need to put a form around the entire vote button and the text area? Or can I get away with just having a form around the textarea in a different location? I only ask as the design of it means that all the options are in a wrapper and there is a single textarea box in a different wrapper next to the options.

Comment: There are lots and lots of ways to implement this. You could wrap the entire lot in a form and check which button was clicked to submit it ... or use javascript to update a hidden field when typing into the message box so that each vote button can be a different form ... or change the vote buttons into a group of radio buttons styled as buttons and have a single submit button ... so many options. But whatever you do you must use a form if you want to submit data from the input field.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks :-) the javascript idea sounds like something I can do fairly easily. I'm not sure on how to add it to the `def upvote`, would I add something like `message: user_message` to the `Answer.create` and add `user_message` to the `text_area` in my view?